# Plot a parabola's property

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to plot something like this
[image: pictrre]

I'm sure it is possible to solve everything mathematically and use something like `\addplot`, but maybe there is an easier way to do it.

I decided to plot it approximately and here's what I have already done:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8]
    \draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);
    \draw (-1.5,-3) parabola[parabola height=2cm] +(3,0);
    \draw (1,0) -- (1,-1.888);
    \filldraw[black] (0,-2) circle (1pt);
    \node at (-0.2,-2) {$F$};
    \draw (0,-2) -- (1,-1.888);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives me
[image]

and as you can see it's not very accurate.
Is there any smart solution to my problem?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a completely math related solution without any hardcoded numbers. Simply change `\f` variable to shift the focus and `\a` to chose the X coordinate of intersection point

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
    parabola(\x) = 1/(-4*\f)*\x^2;
}]

\def\f{3}
\def\a{3}

\begin{axis}
[
every axis plot post/.style={black},
axis lines=none,
samples=50,
no markers,
domain=-10:10
]

%directrix
\addplot (x, \f); 
%parabola
\addplot (x, {parabola(x)} ); 
%focus node
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt, "$F$" right] at (0, -\f) {};
%draw equal lines to parabola
\draw (\a,\f) coordinate (A) -- (\a, {parabola(\a)} ) coordinate (B) -- (0,-\f) coordinate (C);
\coordinate (D) at ({-2*\f/(\a)*(\f-parabola(\a))+\a}, \f);
%draw tangent line
\addplot[restrict y to domain=-10:2] (x, {2/(-4*\f)*(\a)*(x-\a)+parabola(\a)} );

%draw angles
\ifnum\a>0
    \pic["$\varphi$", draw, angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle=A--B--D};
    \pic["$\alpha$", draw, angle eccentricity=1.5, angle radius=10, double] {angle=D--B--C};
\else
    \pic["$\varphi$", draw, angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle=D--B--A};
    \pic["$\alpha$", draw, angle eccentricity=1.5, angle radius=10, double] {angle=C--B--D};
\fi

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, very good!! Perhaps you can use the same letter for both angles? Only an idea, as alpha=phi

Comment: @JuanCastaño tried to replicated OP's hand-drawn image as as close as possible. It looked to me like φ and α.

Comment: You' re right, of course. I didn't see it!!!

Comment: Wow, that's very clever, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

I'd go for a math approach here, and probably the `tkz-euclide` package.

But, using only Ti*k*Z and your parabola:

```tex
\draw (-1.5,-3) parabola[parabola height=2cm] +(3,0);
```

The parabola passes through the points `(±1.5,-3)` and its vertex is at the midpoint and `2cm` above, that is, `V(0,-1)`. So it's very easy to obtain the equation, the tangent line, etc.

A complete solution:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]
%   parabola
    \draw[thick] (-1.5,-3) parabola[parabola height=2cm] +(3,0);
    \node at (-2,-1.5) {$y=-\frac{8}{9}x^2-1$};
%   parabola, equation y=-8/9x^2-1
%   \draw[red] plot [domain=-1.5:1.5] (\x,-8/9*\x*\x-1);
%   directrix
    \draw (-3,-1+9/32) --++ (6,0);
%   focus F
    \coordinate (F) at (0,-1-9/32);
    \fill (F) circle (1pt) node[below] {$F$};
%   tantent point T at x=1
    \coordinate (T) at (1,-8/9-1);
    \coordinate (P) at (1,0);
    \draw (P) -- (T) -- (F);
%   tangent, equation y=-16/9(x-1)-1-8/9
%   \draw[red] plot[domain=-1:2] (\x,{-16/9*(\x-1)-1-8/9});
    \coordinate (A) at (-1,5/3);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,-33/9);
    \draw[teal] (A) -- (B);
%   circle, center T, radius \r
    \pgfmathsetmacro\r{17/9-23/32}
    \draw[orange,dashed] (T) circle (\r);
%   angles
    \pic[draw,angle radius=7mm,anchor=north east,"$\alpha$"] {angle = A--T--F};
    \pic[draw,angle radius=8mm,anchor= west     ,"$\alpha$"] {angle = P--T--A};
%   coordinates used
    \foreach\i in {A,B,P,T}
      \fill[red] (\i) circle (1pt) node[right] {$\i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way I really like that you draw a circle at the point T - it really adds geometrical beauty!

Comment: @DanielNeskorodov why didn't you describe the **context** of the figure, so the helpers can save time to help you. By the way, Juan is so enthusiastic in guessing and adding the dashed circle.

Comment: @BlackMild what context are you talking about? I wanted to draw exactly what I drew in my question. I said about this circle just because I have never thought about parabolas this way and that's all. This irony about guessing is out of place

Comment: @DanielNeskorodov Most beginners are separating the figure from its mathematical context. Some figures describe its underlying maths, but not your figure

Answer (score 2):

My try. Not so beautiful but rather intuitive and mathematical:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={para(\t)=(-\t*\t);} ] %% <-----> define your parabola (chage it to any)
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yfocus}{(1-(para(1)-para(-1))*(para(1)-para(-1)))/4*(para(1)+para(-1)-para(0))+para(0)} % <--> y-coordinate of focus of parabola ax^2+bx+c  (do not change)
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xfocus}{-(para(1)-para(-1))/2*(para(1)+para(-1)-para(0))} % <--> x-coordinate of focus of parabola ax^2+bx+c (do not change)
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xpara}{1} % <--> x-coord of an arbitrary point on your parabola (change the 1)
        
        %!!!! do not change below !!!
        
        \draw [blue, thick, x=1cm, y=1cm] plot [domain=-2:2, samples=100, smooth] (\x,{para(\x)});
        \draw [blue, thick, x=1cm, y=1cm]  (\xpara,{para(\xpara)}) node[circle, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt, fill= red] {};
        \filldraw[blue, thick, x=1cm, y=1cm] ({\xfocus},{\yfocus}) circle(2pt);
        \draw (-2,{-\yfocus}) -- (2,{-\yfocus});
        
        \draw ({\xfocus},{\yfocus}) -- (\xpara,{para(\xpara)}) -- (\xpara,-\yfocus);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]